# android opengl api sample: Spritetext

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to draw a green point with the text in the sample code of android opengl: spritetext(the code please visit the following site: https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/source/9ca6f2c0573e7c6e76515be664e633f03a1a4358:samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/LabelMaker.java).
 I added the following code in the function:  public int add(GL10 gl, Drawable background, String text, Paint textPaint,
int minWidth, int minHeight) of  the LakerMarker.java:

```
  Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setStrokeWidth(20);
    if (drawText) {
        mCanvas.drawText(text,
                u + padding.left + centerOffsetWidth,
                vBase + padding.top + centerOffsetHeight,
                textPaint);// in the sample code, just this.
        mCanvas.drawPoint( u + padding.left + centerOffsetWidth,
                vBase + padding.top + centerOffsetHeight,
                p);// this code is to draw the green point
    }
```

Then I run, get the following image result.I want to only the left green point with each text, but there were two points(one is in left, another one is in right) with each text, How to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: what IDE(editor) are you using?

Comment: I used the eclipse to run the code

Comment: No one can solve this issue? Please give your hand!